# Pandas time-series: aggregate by date and transpose

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following time series dataframe:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime([
        '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03',
        '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03']), 
    'Ticker': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL'],
    'Price': ['8', '10', '12', '100', '200', '50']})
```

```
          date   Ticker   Price
0   2020-04-01        A       8
1   2020-04-02        A      10
2   2020-04-03        A      12
3   2020-04-01     AAPL     100
4   2020-04-02     AAPL     200
5   2020-04-03     AAPL      50
```

The final result should look like:

```
dataframe_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020-04-01', '2020-04-02','2020-04-03']), 
    'A': [8, 10, 12],
    'AAPL': [100, 200, 50]})
```

```
          date   A  AAPL
0   2020-04-01   8   100
1   2020-04-02  10   200
2   2020-04-03  12    50
```

Initially I tried using the groupby function but with not much success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: I checked that question and it answers how to pivot a dataframe. That said, the top answer is so long that it feels overwhelming and intrincate; I learned how to do it way faster from just reading the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are trying to do is called pivoting. That is, creating new columns from the categorical values of a column.

You can do either of these (same results):

```
df = dataframe.set_index("date").pivot(columns="Ticker", values="Price")
```

---

```
df = dataframe.pivot(index="date", columns="Ticker", values="Price")
```

It is important to set the index; otherwise, the pivot will not know how to combine rows and you will get extra rows with NaN values. For the sample data, without the index, it would not know to treat rows 0 and 3 in your base data as the same date.

Comment: Why `.set_index("date")` instead of `.pivot(index="date", ...)`?